# Width of a dual-line based on values out of the attribute table in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, line, arcgis-10.4

Is it possible to symbolize the width of a dual-line automatically by a value out of the attribute table in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.1?

In my case, i have hundreds of different entries with the width of a sewer in the attribute table field and wanted to have this scaled distance between the two lines of the dual-line.

Comment: You should include in the body of your post the fact that you are trying to set up the dual line in symbology, rather than just including a tag for symbology only.  Initially I thought you wanted to create dual line features in a feature class.

Comment: Of course you are right! I changed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to create dual line symbols that reflect a field value is to use a Proportional Symbol.

To set it up for a dual line proportional symbol first choose "Proportional symbols" under the Quantities category within the "Show:" group box. Set the "Value:" in the Fields group to your width field.  Make sure the "Unit:" combobox is set to the correct distance units for those values and then choose "Width" in the data represents group box that will appear (or "Distance from center" if it was a width around a centerline).

[image: Proportional Symbol Set Up]

To change the symbol from a single line into a dual line, click on the button within the Base Symbol group box.  In the Symbol Selector dialog window click on the "Freeway" symbol (or a similar symbol like "Stacked Multi Roadway" or "Toll Road"), which is made up of two overlapping lines of different widths and colors.

[image: Symbol Selector]

If you want to change the red interior line color to match your map background color or change the color of the surrounding dual lines, click on the "Edit Symbol..." button in the Symbol Selector and change the colors of the appropriate line component.

The picture below shows the result of these settings after I changed the interior line color to white to match my map background and adjusted the interior line width from 2.6 points to 1.8 points to have more of the dual lines show through so that they would appear more solid:

[image: Proportional Dual Line Symbol]

However, these symbols act as though a reference scale has been set on your data frame and the symbols will show the width as it is in the real world.  This may not be pleasing at all scales.  Some ways to trick it is to change the units to a false unit type to make the symbol shrink or grow.  For example, if I zoom out to a scale of 1:24000, which is about 6 times bigger than my first picture, using a Unit of Meters looks better Cartographically, even though the symbols are not to scale and are merely proportional to each other.

Here is the symbol shown in feet (to scale) at 1:24000:

[image: Symbols in Feet at 1:24000]

Here is the symbol shown after I changed the Proportional symbol units to Meters (not to scale, but still proportionally correct relative to each other) at 1:24000:

[image: Symbols in Meters at 1:24000]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution!
Thats not exactly what i expected, but it will solve my problem also